# how to access node express-react app from external computer on same network

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, react-router

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this working:

my project has a folder structure where two node processes run.
one for the express app. and one for the react app.

I'm just trying now to access this from any other computer on the network, and it is failing.

I have a re-route function I suspect may be causing the issue.

index.js of server

```
const cors = require("cors");

const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

const port =5001;
const router = require('./router');


const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      credentials: true
    }
  });
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

the router js file consists of.

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.redirect('https://http://localhost:3000/');
})

module.exports = router;
```

When I try to access the react app from any computer on the network, it times out, unable to find anything. I've tried 3000,5001, no port... nothing is working...

the router function is also related (if memory servers) to socket.io stuff - which is why it was put in.

Comment: `res.redirect('https://http://localhost:3000/');` is malformed

Comment: yes: I have also tried modifying that: to my IP address. to 0.0.0.0, so a few other things... nothing I have tried allows a computer on the network to gain access - regardless of the https:// in front or not.

Comment: Are you trying to access the server from the other computer using the IP of the computer it's running on (i.e. `10.0.0.x:5000` depending on your router setup)? You may need to forward ports etc.

Comment: You should do an ipconfig on windows/ifconfig on mac/linux to find the ip of the computer running the server. after you have found the app, lets say its "192.168.0.10" then on the other computer just write in the browser "http:// 
 192.168.0.10:5001  /" 5001 is your port number (Remove the spaces). also I do not understand why are you redirecting to port 3000, and also the url syntax is wrong so it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Are these apps running on a Linux box?

Comment: I access the web-app via port 3000: where I have the client side code. I have a xammp stack running just fine, and I know what my IP is.  I have modified the above code  - the redirect a few different ways. I assumed I would access it from the same port on another computer... although I have tried both (3000:5001) neither worked under any configuration I have found so far.

Comment: If you've done what I said and its still not working then it might be a problem with your firewall not allowing any connections

Comment: I have an xammp stack running on the same network, which runs perfectly fine. I do not believe it is a firewall issue.

Comment: it was the firewall